# Type synonyms for implicits?

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming, higher-order-functions, higher-kinded-types

Can you create a type synonym for a function that takes an implicit parameter?

For shortening things like

```
def findOnlyOne(f: Node => Boolean)(n: Node)(implicit errorType: String => ValidationError): Either[ValidationError, Node] = ...
```

which if errorType were not implicit could be something like:

```
type ValidationF = (Node => Boolean) => Node => (String => U) => Either[U, Node]
findOnlyOne: ValidationF = f => n => onErr => ...
```

I'm guessing you can't because the name of the implicit parameter is significant to it unlike other types, so you would need something higher order like

```
ImplicitFunction[myImplicitParam, T]
```

for `implicit myImplicitParam: T`

Difficult to google for because combinations of "type", "implicit", "synonym" don't communicate that I'm looking for making a type synonym containing an implicit type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that SAM already provides more or less what you want:

```
trait Node
trait ValidationError
import scala.util.Either

abstract class ValidationF {
  // single abstract method without implicits
  def apply_impl(
    f: Node => Boolean, 
    n: Node, 
    errorType: String => ValidationError
  ): Either[ValidationError, Node]

  // actual `apply` with implicits
  def apply
    (f: Node => Boolean)
    (n: Node)
    (implicit errorType: String => ValidationError)
  : Either[ValidationError, Node] = {
    apply_impl(f, n, errorType)
  }
}

val findOnlyOne: ValidationF = 
  (f, n, onErr) => (??? : Either[ValidationError, Node])
```

It works only with tupled parameters, not for long chains of curried functions, though...

If you insist on initializing these things with the curried function, then you can create a separate factory method for that:

```
object ValidationF {
  def apply(
    curried: 
      (Node => Boolean) => 
      Node => 
      (String => ValidationError) => 
      Either[ValidationError, Node]
  ): ValidationF = new ValidationF {
    def apply_impl(
      f: Node => Boolean, 
      n: Node, 
      errorType: String => ValidationError
  ): Either[ValidationError, Node] = {
      curried(f)(n)(errorType)
    }
  }
}

val findOnlyTwo = ValidationF(f => n => onErr => 
  (??? : Either[ValidationError, Node])
)
```

It's exactly one character longer than the `: ValidationF = ...` version.